# How detect repetition in 2D array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, repeat

How can I detect repetition in a 2D array?

Example:

If I have this matrix:

```
AABBAABBXX
CCDDCCDDXX
XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX
```

Where X is any other element in array

How can I detect that the group

```
AABB
CCDD
```

is repeated in the matrix?

My goal is to create a Javascript algorithm that detect this repetition and propose same repetition near.

Example:

```
AABBAABB(AABB)
CCDDCCDD(CCDD)
XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Thanks all for reply!

Edit: in JS my array has this format

```
M[0]={A,C,X,X,X,X}
M[1]={A,C,X,X,X,X}  
M[2]={B,D,X,X,X,X}  
...
```

I can add element in all position of the matrix, for every insert I must check with an algorithm if new element create a group repetition and only in this case suggest same repetition near (in horizontal and vertical direction, row/column)

## Another example

```
M[0] = [F,F,F,H,H,H,I,I]
M[1] = [L,L,L,L,L,L,I,D]
M[2] = [F,F,F,H,H,H,I,N]
M[3] = [L,L,L,L,L,L,K,D]
```

After processing with js script

```
M[0] = [F,F,F,H,H,H,I,I]
M[1] = [L,L,L,L,L,L,I,D]
M[2] = [F,F,F,H,H,H,I,N]
M[3] = [L,L,L,L,L,L,K,D]
M[4] = [F,F,F,H,H,H,*,*]
M[5] = [L,L,L,L,L,L,*,*]

(* is null value)
```

Comment: let us know what you have tried

Comment: and... in your target algorithms, what are you going to pad the bottom rows with (the ones that are XXXX) if their pattern is not repeating.... just asking...

Comment: Instead of showing a block of characters, show the sample data in an actual JavaScript structure, and the JavaScript structure that you expect from it.... and the code you have tried with.

Comment: If you want to find all repeats in usefull time (for big matrices) that's already a quiet tough job in a string (read 1D) but is described in "The Runs Theorem" (2014). If you know the pattern that might be repeated it gets a lot easier.

Comment: My problem isn't find determinated pattern, but find repetition in matrix and duplicate it.

Comment: I can't find solutions... any help?